# Refer to an object in multiple collection and have the order within each affect some properties

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop

This is a hard one to explain.

I have a collection of boxes, each with their own contents. The box can appear on more than one shelf and if the contents ever get changed I want to reflect those changes globally.

So I have a global collection of boxes, and from this I create a box collection per shelf as well.

My problem is knowing where the box is positioned on each shelf. Let's just worry about X position.

In one case my box might be sat in the middle of a shelf and it's X position would be 44cm.
In another case that same box might be at the start of a shelf and it's X position is 0.

I need to access it as Shelf(id).Box(id).PosX

But that would always give one answer and the answer should change depending on parent shelf.

I know there are many answers to the issue but I'm hoping someone has a more elegant way than some of the things I've been planning.

Answer (score 2):

Should the box know where it is? Probably not - you should be able to ask the shelf about its contents, which would mean asking the shelf where the box is.

```
myShelf.GetBoxPosition(boxId).PosX
```

So the box doesn't have any positional information, which makes sense as it can be in multiple locations. The shelf knows where its contents are and can answer your question.

The assumption here is that the box doesn't appear multiple times on the same shelf - otherwise it would have to return a collection of box positions, rather than a single box position.

Comment: That's one approach I've considered. Another is that the box can reference back to it's parent, to call a method within the parent to get it's own PosX. Neither approach is ideal but this approach lets me retain the coding structure present across the board for many other objects I use (which can't be multi-placed). i.e. myObj.PosX

The box, like every object, has native positional information which pertain to it "default" shelf if you like. It's just different in such that it can be placed in "virtual" shelves which act as different views on the same data.

Comment: The other thing I've considered but can't get to, is since I'm building a dictionary of boxes within the shelf, and I assume the dictionary will retain the order I add them in, then I can calculate the PosX based on widths and so on. But I can't find  away to get a dictionary item by index (rather than key).